Poblems with the partial trace in Julia
My problem hinges on the computation of reduced density matrices for a given density operator. To this aim I employed the function 'ptrace' belonging to the 'QuantumInformation' Julia package. You can easily check that the documentation says it receives three arguments : the density operator to trace out, the dimensions of each subsystems and the indices of the subsystem(s) to trace out. I successfully did a task involving this function, but then some issues came up with another  similar task.
I tried to see what happens with a toy example: I created a 8x8 matrix by mean of  tensor product of three 2x2 arbitrarily chose matrices and I tried to devise each one of them, as well as the subsystems AB, AC and BC, exploiting the ptrace function. However, I correctly obtained only few subsystems and not all of them. This little example paved the way to a new  method-based approach...But first, let me show you what I meant to say :
    using LinearAlgebra     
    using QuantumInformation     
    ρ1 = [0.4 0.2; 0.2 0.6]; ρ2 = [0.5 0; 0 0.5]; ρ3 = [0.1 0; 0.3 0]     
    ρ_tot = kron(ρ1,ρ2,ρ3)     
    ρ_12 = ptrace(ρ_tot,[2,2,2],[3])     
    ρ_13 = ptrace(ρ_tot,[2,2,2],[2])     
    ρ_23 = ptrace(ρ_tot,[2,2,2],[1])     
    ρ_1 = ptrace(ρ_tot,[2,2,2],[2,3])
    ρ_2 = ptrace(ρ_tot,[2,2,2],[1,3])  
    ρ_3 = ptrace(ρ_tot,[2,2,2],[1,2])                                               
    kron(ρ1,ρ2)                             
    kron(ρ1,ρ3)                             
    kron(ρ2,ρ3)      

ρ_12, ρ_1 and ρ_2 don't work well because ρ_1 != ρ1,ρ_12 != kron(ρ1,ρ2) and ρ_13 != kron(ρ1,ρ3), as I set out to show...
So I tried to devise a function realizing the same task on my own, but I didn't succeed: Indeed, altough I used a Python-to-Julia converter from translating a seemingly working Python function for doing the partial trace into the Julia syntax, I encounter an error and I am not able to slightly modify the code for making it work properly. Here is the snippet I am talking about, that I show for clarity:
    using LinearAlgebra

    function partial_trace(rho::Matrix, dims::Vector{Int}, sys::Int=1)
    
         dims_ = dims
        
        reshaped_rho = reshape(rho, dims_..., dims_...)

       
        reshaped_rho = permutedims(reshaped_rho, [1:sys-1; sys+1:length(dims); sys; length(dims)+sys])

        traced_out_rho = tr(reshaped_rho, length(dims)+1, length(dims)+2)

        
        dims_untraced = dims_[setdiff(1:length(dims), sys)]
        rho_dim = prod(dims_untraced)
        return reshape(traced_out_rho, rho_dim, rho_dim)
    end
    rho_A = (rand(Float64, 4,4 ))
    ρ_A = rho_A/tr(rho_A)
    rho_B = (rand(Float64, 3, 3))
    ρ_B = rho_B/tr(rho_B)
    rho_C = (rand(Float64, 2, 2)) 
    ρ_C = rho_C/tr(rho_C)
    
    ρ_AB = kron(ρ_A,ρ_B)
    ρ_AC = kron(ρ_A,ρ_C)
    ρ_ABC= kron(ρ_AB,ρ_C) 

    
    ρ_AB_test = partial_trace(ρ_ABC, [4, 3, 2], 3)
    ρ_AC_test = partial_trace(ρ_ABC, [4, 3, 2], 2)
    ρ_A_test = partial_trace(ρ_AB_test, [4, 3], 2)
    ρ_B_test = partial_trace(ρ_AB_test, [4, 3], 1)
    ρ_C_test = partial_trace(ρ_AC_test, [4, 2], 1)

How can I fix this problem? And if it is not worthing doing so,  is there anyone able to give me  a function  to perform  the partial trace correctly somewhere?

Without looking too deep into your code, the documentation says that ptrace only takes pure states, but e.g. your first state is not pure. Is this fixing the problem already?

Hello sir @qntdni, thank you for replying. I didn't understand that 'ptrace' only deals with pure Quantum states...Nevertheless, it seems the issues of that toy example are fixed whenever I consider matrices whose diagonal entries sum up to one: indeed, by slightly modifying the third matrix s.t. its diagonal entrie are 0.1 and 0.9, I easily come up with all the expected results !However, something seems to go wrong when dealing with the following mixed state built on three qubits A,B,C: \rho = p*|W><W|_ABC + (1-p)* kron(|EPR><EPR_AB,|0><0|_C), p \in [0,1]... May I create another post for it?

I think the problems is your ρ3 is not a correct density matrix. A correct density matrix must be a Hermitian matrix with the trace equal to one.
